# Make linphone only use g729 for all calls by default

Tags: android, audio, linphone

Where can I change my application's preference to use G729 codec by default for all calls in linphone?

I have successfully compiled the library and I can find the codec inside my audio codec list, but I want to set g729 as the default codec.

Comment: from the both end you have to do manual setting from linphone app goto setting->audio codec->select g729.

Comment: @bhaveshkaila : Thanks for your reply, in my server configuration I have disabled any codec except g729, and I am writing my own application over linphone, and I don't want to show setting screen, I want to set g729 as default codec for all calls, and I want to know how to be able to change the preference to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Enable g729 codec in settings View to Bool Value YES like

```
[self.settingsstore setBool:YES forkey:@"g729_Preference"];
```

in `viewwillappear` method in IASKAppSettingsViewController Class.
once try it.